# How to establish a connection between Rundeck and Windows Server?

Tags: linux, windows, rundeck

I want to establish a connection between Rundeck and Windows server. Currently the rundeck I am using does not support Windows and I want to establish a connection as one of the job runs only on Windows.

Is it possible to connect to Linux and then the Linux box establish the connection to Windows server?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

"Currently the rundeck I am using does not support Windows" -> can you provide0 us more details about this? Please clarify 
* if you don't have direct network access to windows host ? or you want to establish a direct connection to windows.

If this is the case you may use Project Config > Default Node Executor > "WinRM Node Executor Python" This will allow you to connect to windows hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to connect to Windows-based systems is by using [PyWinRM](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin) plugin, that node executor is out of the box with Rundeck.

Check about how to [configure](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#configuration) it.

Keep on mind that you need to [configure](https://yallalabs.com/automation-tool/how-to-add-windows-node-on-rundeck-server-and-execute-jobs-using-winrm-plugin/) your windows node to works properly with WinRM protoco (check: "Step 2./ Configure a Windows Server for WinRM", the rest of that guide is about the old WinRM plugin "overthere-WinRM", but Step 2 section explain perfectly how to configure your Windows box).